# Minimizing the pain in implementing printable reports

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, reporting, printing

How do you minimize the pain in your development process when it comes to reporting?

For web frameworks, there is a pretty straightforward way to both produce content as well as graphically design it; content is represented semantically through HTML, and the design is separately specified through CSS.  And browsers are fairly consistent with how they render the output (and the inconsistencies are well-known and can be planned for).  There are even WYSIWYG editors to help out less-CSS-savvy graphical designers.

But what do we do about print content?

At one company, I created a process that worked like this: A script generated a semantic representation through XML.  The XML was passed through XSLT to generate an XML-FO document.  Then, this was passed to another tool (Apache FOP, I believe) to generate a PDF.  This worked well for that company.

At this company, however, output appearance matters to management, and we have a graphical designer.  Currently, we are using a reporting tool (XtraReports from Developer Express, version 8.1).  It isn't bad; it outputs to a variety of formats, has a WYSIWYG designer, reports are implemented through C# classes, and it supports data binding to data sets (unfortunately, not POCO's).  However, we have some major pain points with this setup:

- The reporting framework has major limitations on how you can lay out and group your reporting bands
- Presentable elements, especially charts, lack the capabilities we need to fine-tune and achieve the look of our mock-ups.
- There is no good way to share styles and layout among reports akin to what we can get through CSS.
- Good composability of reusable parts is very hard to implement.  So we end up with a lot of copy & paste inheritance of functionality; this is bad news whenever we need to make sweeping changes across all reports.

Now, maybe there's some kick-ass framework out there that can eliminate the pains of reporting frameworks, but I assume that they all have their weaknesses.  Do you have a framework or process that works well for you and reduces the pain points inherent in reporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/) is a really cool tool which allows you to use HTML or XML styled with CSS (including [CSS paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html) for printing) and generate PDFs from it.

Comment: My goodness, that looks perfect.  I'll have to experiment with that.  Have you personally used this product?  If so, it'd be nice if you elaborated on your experience with using this.

Comment: I've used for a very large project and had great experience with it. You can just create whatever HTML/CSS you like and it makes a PDF. Supports CSS as well as any browser I've used. The documentation has some good info on how it supports paged media: http://princexml.com/doc/7.0/

Comment: Dang, 3800 USD for a site license.  Might be worth it if it can speed up our development process, but phew!

Comment: I am now working on implementing a solution using this product.  So far, it appears to be a much better tool for our needs.

Answer (score 1):

Option #1 : Adobe Acrobat is really nice. You can design form enabled PDFs and then use something like [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/) to manipulate the PDF document. You can create template PDF's that you dump your generated stuff into. I've done this before and it was pretty successful. I also used POCO objects nicely.

Option #2 : You could start creating XPS documents, which is XML based anyways. And they can be easily converted to PDF if necessary.

Option #3 : Run for your life.(might not be an option)

Comment: Option 3 seems the most sane option.  However, I also like option #1; however, I'm unsure of how to modify a PDF to effectively use it as a template.  Could you elaborate on this or provide a link to a good article if this is something commonly done?

Answer (score 0):

[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear) is a nice product. It's based on Java but you can also work with ASP.NET. There is a bridge. The .NET version is in work if you want work with POCO. Because the Java version can work with POJO that the coming .NET version will also work with POCO.